# How to efficiently get unique combinations of a list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq, combinations

I have a single list of objects that I want to make unique combinations from.

The objects that I have are (CityObj);

```
public string City_Name;
public int Population;
double xcord;
double ycord;
double zcord;
```

The result would be a list that contains a new object (CityComboObj)

```
public string City_NameA;
public int PopulationA;
double xcordA;
double ycordA;
double zcordA;
public string City_NameB;
public int PopulationB;
double xcordB;
double ycordB;
double zcordB;
```

A sample of the dataset is as follows;

- City1 | 3840 | 42 | -12 | 5
- City2 | 39402 | 1 | 59 | -5
- City3 | 5934 | 99 | -55 | 3
- City4 | 12394 | -56 | 9 | 16

The resultant list of objects would look like;

City1 | 3840 | 42 | -12 | 5 City2 | 39402 | 1 | 59 | -5

City1 | 3840 | 42 | -12 | 5 City3 | 5934 | 99 | -55 | 3

City1 | 3840 | 42 | -12 | 5 City4 | 12394 | -56 | 9 | 16

City2 | 39402 | 1 | 59 | -5 City3 | 5934 | 99 | -55 | 3

City2 | 39402 | 1 | 59 | -5 City4 | 12394 | -56 | 9 | 16

City3 | 5934 | 99 | -55 | 3 City4 | 12394 | -56 | 9 | 16

As you can see its only the unique results returned.

Currently I am using a horribly inefficient apporach to do going this;

```
foreach (var element in CityListA)
            {
            if (!CityListB.Any(o => o.City_NameA == element.City_NameA && o.City_NameB == element.City_NameB))
                {
                    if (!CityListB.Any(o => o.City_NameA == element.City_NameB && o.City_NameB == element.City_NameA))
                    {
                        CityListB.add(element)
                    }
                }
            }
```

In a nutshell the approach is to take two lists one full and one empty, compare each element of the full list with the empty list to see if it exists or the transpose exists and if it doesn't add it.

It works but it is slow, is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: You could combine the `Any` calls, for one.

Comment: Your problem is "I have a sequence of unique items of length n. I wish to generate all subsequences of length k <= n". I wrote a series of articles on different techniques to do that. The series begins here: https://ericlippert.com/2014/10/13/producing-combinations-part-one/ But if you're not interested in the theory and just want the code, it's here: https://gist.github.com/ericlippert/69c9e93b366f8cc5d6ac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Your code needs some reengineering, for example:

internal class CityObjs : List<CityObj> 
{
}

internal class CityObj
{
  public string City_Name;
  public int Population;
  double xcord;
  double ycord;
  double zcord;
}

internal class CityComboObj
{
  internal CityObj CityA ;
  internal CityObj CityB ;
  internal CityComboObj(CityObj A,CityObj B) { CityA=A ; CityB=B;} 
}

internal class CityComboObjs: List<CityComboObj> 
{
}
```

Assuming that the list CityObjs is initialized:

```
CityComboObjs = new CityComboObjs() ;
for (int i=0;i<CityObjs.Count-1;i++) for (int j=i+1;j<CityObjs.Count;j++) 
  CityComboObjs.Add(new CityComboObj(CityObjs[i],CityObjs[j]) ;
```

Comment: Thanks, ultimately this did what I was looking for and at a fraction of the time(and CPU) cost.

Answer (score 0):

This actually works. Just replace simple integers with real objects. The idea of this code is to do it more efficiently, as you asked, without checking if the pair already exists. In your case `myList[i]` will return a *CITY* object

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myList = (new []{1 , 2, 3, 4}).ToList();
        var newList =  new List<ListObject>();
        var count = myList.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
        {         
            for(int j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
            {   
                newList.Add(new ListObject(){ I = myList[i], J = myList[j]});
            }
        }
        newList.ForEach(x =>  Console.WriteLine(x));
    }

    class ListObject
    {
        public int I {get; set;}
        public int J {get; set;}

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return I + " - " + J;
        }
    }
}
```

> Output
>   1 - 2
>   1 - 3
>   1 - 4
>   2 - 3
>   2 - 4
>   3 - 4